# How to write query for condition of some objects must NOT be in array of objects and one of some other objects Must be in array of object?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have student collection of mongo documents like the following:

```
{
  name: 'XYZ',
  age: 26,
  education: [
    { title: 'abc', university: 'pqr', grade: 'A' },
    { title: 'def', university: 'uvq', grade: 'B' },
    { title: 'ghi', university: 'xyz', grade: 'A' },
    { title: 'jkl', university: 'pqr', grade: 'B' },
    { title: 'mno', university: 'uvw', grade: 'C' }
  ]
}, {
  name: 'QQQ',
  age: 26,
  education: [
    { title: 'abc', university: 'pqr', grade: 'A' },
    { title: 'ghi', university: 'xyz', grade: 'A' },
    { title: 'jkl', university: 'xyz', grade: 'B' },
    { title: 'mno', university: 'pqr', grade: 'C' }
  ]
}
```

Now I want to write a query in which I want students who **MUST HAVE** completed their

> `{education-title:'abc' with grade A}` **OR** `{education-title:'def'
>   with grade B}`

BUT **MUST NOT** have completed

> `{education-title:'jkl' with university:pqr}`
>   **AND**`{education-title:'mno' with university:uvw}`

If observed carefully my document with the `name: QQQ` satisfies all the criteria and should be the output of the query. I'm trying to solve these conditions by using `$or` and `$and` operators inside `$elemMatch` operator, but not sure whether my approach is correct or not. My query looks like the following

```
studentModel.aggregate({
{
  $match: {
    'education': $elemMatch: {
      $or: [{
          'title': 'abc',
          'grade': 'A'
        },
        {
          'title': 'def',
          'grade': 'B'
        }
      ]},
      $not: {
        $elemMatch: {
          $and: [{
              'title': 'jkl',
              'university': 'pqr'
            },
            {
              'title': 'mno',
              'university': 'uvw'
            }
          ]
        }
    }
  }
});
```

above code is working and giving me the output but I'm not sure if it will work with millions of record and still produce the expected output or not. I just wanna make sure if my approach of using $and AND $or operator inside $elemMatch is correct or not?

Comment: You could probably expand on this by showing more than one sample document and making it so that at least one document would match your conditions and others would demonstrably not. My interpretation of your logic is that the only document you presently provided would in fact **NOT** be match for the conditions since the array includes the `'title'` and `'university'` values which you are asking to exclude on. So you really should show at least one positive with some negatives. And please pay attention to the edits for presenting a valid data format people can copy and paste and test with.

Comment: okay thank you, @Neil Lunn, for your suggestion, I will try to rectify the errors

Comment: I have extended my question's details and now I have added the document with name:QQQ which satisfy the given criteria

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your query it incorrectly selects the first document, and that is because the second condition inside the [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) actually can never match an element since it is not possible for [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) to contain "multiple conditions" for the same properties **on the same element**. Which is what [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) is making the distinction of in "matching multiple conditions on the same array element". Hence the naming.

The correct way, is instead to list "separate" [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) statements and wrap them with [`$all`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/all/):

```
db.getCollection('students').find({
  "education": {
    "$elemMatch": {
      "$or": [
        { "title": "abc", "grade": "A" },
        { "title": "def", "grade": "B" }
      ]  
    }, 
    "$not": {
      "$all": [
        { "$elemMatch": {
          "title": "jkl", "university": "pqr"
        }},
        { "$elemMatch": {
          "title": "mno", "university": "uvw"  
        }} 
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

This correctly only selects the second `QQQ` document from the provided samples.

Comment: thank you very much, Neil for your answer, but I was wondering if $or operator could be used inside $elemMatch then why not $and operator be used there?

Comment: @PointNetworks Because `$or` means "either" so it is possible for a "single element" to have "one or the other" sets of conditions. But `$and` means "both" and therefore a "singular element" can never have "both". But I thought that's what I actually say in the answer, even if I did not say the `$or` "either" thing.